# Como posso ter esse marker que azul na minha aplicacao?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como implementar esse marker na minha app?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depois de obter uma referência ao mapa utilize o método [setMyLocationEnabled.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29)

```
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Deverá declarar as seguinte permissões no AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Muito obrigado solucionou o meu problema